# How can I merge and count MySQL rows that are identical except for an ID column?

Tags: mysql, count

I want to be able to merge rows and find out how many are the same excluding the ID. For example, if I was to have this table:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  ID     |  Col 1    |  Col 2    |
+---------+-----------+ ----------+
|  1      |  1        |  5        |
|  2      |  1        |  5        |
|  3      |  4        |  9        |
|  4      |  3        |  9        |
|  5      |  1        |  5        |
|  6      |  1        |  5        |
|  7      |  1        |  5        |
|  8      |  4        |  9        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

It would become:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  ID     |  Col 1    |  Col 2    |  Count  |
+---------+-----------+ ----------+---------+
|  1      |  1        |  5        | 5       |
|  2      |  4        |  9        | 2       |
|  3      |  3        |  9        | 1       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

What would the query for this be?

Comment: What do you think? What did you try? Where did you fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beside the ID column in your result, to me it looks like you need:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Count(Col1)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Comment: I think your group by is wrong because the ID is unique - it should be grouping by col1,col2

Answer (score 3):

```
select col1,col2,count(*) as `count`
from table
group by col1,col2
```